# Finding all real solutions to $y^2=x^3-3x^2+2x$ and $x^2=y^3-3y^2+2y$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Find the all real solutions following system equations:
$$y^2=x^3-3x^2+2x$$
$$x^2=y^3-3y^2+2y$$

---

I was only able to edit and get $x^3-2x^2+2x=y^3-2y^2+2y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtracting the two equations yields
$$(x-y)\left(x^2+xy+y^2-2x-2y+2\right)=0\,.$$
We have
$$x^2+xy+y^2-2x-2y+2=\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{2}y^2+\frac{1}{2}(x+y-2)^2>0\,,$$
as $x=0$, $y=0$, and $x+y-2=0$ cannot be satisfied simultaneously.  (In fact, the minimum value of $x^2+xy+y^2-2x-2y+2$ is $\dfrac23$, which is met if and only if $(x,y)=\left(\dfrac23,\dfrac23\right)$.) Thus, $x=y$ must hold.

Answer (score 2):

$$(x-y)\{x^2+xy+y^2-2(x+y)+2\}=0$$

If $x\ne y$

$$x^2+x(y-2)+y^2-2y+2=0$$

The discriminant is $$-[4(y^2-2y+2)-(y-2)^2]=-[3y^2-4y+4]=-[2y^2+(y-2)^2]<0$$

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$
f(x,y) = y^2-x^3+3x^2-2x\\
f(y,x) = x^2-y^3+3y^2-2y
$$

so

$$
f(x,x) = x^2-x^3+3x^2-2x = 0\Rightarrow {x = 0}\cup{x = 2\pm \sqrt2} 
$$

Attached a plot showing the solutions

[image]

Answer (score 2):

@Cesareo, You give me hint.

---

We get the following equations if we take sides.
$$x^3-2x^2+2x=y^3-2y^2+2y$$

Let  $f(t)=t^3-2t^2+2t$. So $f(x)=f(y)$.

$f'(x)=3x^2-4x+2>2x^2-4x+2=2(x^2-2x+1)=2(x-1)^2\geq 0\Rightarrow f'(x)>0$

Hence, $f$ is a strictly increasing function. So $f$ is $1-1$.

we obtaion $f(x)=f(y)\Rightarrow x=y$

Now, if we take $y=x$ in given system equations:
$$x^2=x^3-3x^2+2x\iff x^3-4x^2+2x=0\iff x(x^2-4x+2)=0$$
Therefore, all solutions are $(0,0),(2+\sqrt{2},2+\sqrt{2}),(2-\sqrt{2},2-\sqrt{2})$.